# A $q$-continued fraction connected to the divisor function?

Tags: continued-fractions, theta-functions, q-series, divisor-counting-function

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403979/4781), the following two continued fractions discussed by Nicco are given,

$$A(q)= \left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q)}{2\,q^{1/4}}\right)^2= \cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1\color{red}-q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1\color{red}-q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1\color{red}-q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}\tag1$$

$$B(q)=\frac{1}{2\,q^{1/2}}\frac{\vartheta_2(0,q^2)}{\vartheta_3(0,q^2)} =\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{q(1\color{blue}+q)^2}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q^2(1\color{blue}+q^2)^2}{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^3(1\color{blue}+q^3)^2}{1-q^7+\ddots}}}}\tag2$$

where $|q|<1$. One can see their beautiful affinity. On a hunch, I decided to investigate the similar cfrac,

$$C(q)=\cfrac{1}{1-q\color{red}-\cfrac{q(1\color{red}-q)^2}{1-q^3\color{red}-\cfrac{q^2(1\color{red}-q^2)^2}{1-q^5\color{red}-\cfrac{q^3(1\color{red}-q^3)^2}{1-q^7\color{red}-\ddots}}}}\tag3$$

**Q1:** Is it true that,

$$C(q) \overset{\color{red}?}= \frac{1}{q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^{2n-1}} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sigma_0(2n+1)\,q^n = 1+2q+2q^2+2q^3+3q^4+\dots\tag4$$

where $\sigma_0(2n+1)$ is the *[divisor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)*? (I've checked it to hundreds of coefficients and it seems to hold. More info at [A099774](https://oeis.org/A099774).) Note that the equality below is known,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma_0(n)\,q^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^n}$$

**Q2:** Can $C(q)$ be also expressed in terms of the *Jacobi theta functions* $\vartheta_k(0,q)$?

Comment: @ccorn: Good to know. I have a feeling that $C(q)$ is expressible by theta functions. See, for example, eq.6 of the [odd divisor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddDivisorFunction.html).

Comment: Regarding $\frac{1}{q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^{2n-1}} \overset{?}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sigma_0(2n+1)\,q^n$, just set $q=r^2$ in the RHS and multiply by $r$, then the series is the odd part of the generating function for $\sigma_0(n)$. Rewrite that one using the known equality, massage the fractions to get rid of $(-1)^n$ in the denominators, then you end up with a sum whose parts are zero for even $n$. Then you can substitute back $r^2=q$, and you get the LHS.

Comment: @ccorn: Thanks. I've removed the second question mark in $(4)$. That just leaves the first one.

Comment: W. r. t. thetanulls: I have checked the usual suspects from my notes and from DLMF (you can search there for `1-q^{2n-1}` which returns quite useful results), no match. Also some (squares of) Jacobi elliptic functions have turned up among the candidates, still no match.

Comment: @ccorn: Since using the [odd divisor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddDivisorFunction.html), we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma_1^{(o)} q^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\, q^n}{1+q^n} = \frac{\vartheta_2^4(0,q) +\vartheta_3^4(0,q)}{24}$$ I just have the _oddest_ wishful feeling that $C(q)$, like $A(q)$ and $B(q)$, should be expressible as well (though maybe more complicated). But thanks for checking your sources.

Comment: Caution: It is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_1^{\text{(o)}} q^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\, q^n}{1+q^n} = \frac{\vartheta_2^4(0,q) + \vartheta_3^4(0,q) - 1}{24}$. Easy to check for $q=0$. Mathworld is full of such typos, and they do seem to ignore bug reports. Cf. [A000593](http://oeis.org/A000593).

Comment: @ccorn: Thanks for the heads-up. I also found this typo for the modular equation $\Omega_7$ that I mentioned at the middle of my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1406001/4781). However, in fairness to Eric, he did create most of that huge resource and the sheer amount of effort to be accurate while type-setting is recipe for _carpal tunnel syndrome_. But, yes, they should respond to bug/typo reports.

Comment: I have the same wishful feeling, [as I had there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377549), but no hit so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to Q1 is *yes*. About Q2, I don't know yet.

As usual, I suppose that $q=\exp(2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau)$
for $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ (complex upper half plane) and define
$$q_n = \exp\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}\tau}{n}$$
Thus we can consider Theta functions to be functions of $\tau$.
I write $\vartheta_k(0\mid\tau)$ instead of $\vartheta_k(0,q_2)$.
This is mostly to avoid multivalue issues with $\vartheta_2$.

**Proposition:** For $q,r\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|q|<1$ and $|r|<1$, we have
$$\cfrac{1}{1-q-\cfrac{r\,(1-q)^2}{1-q^3-\cfrac{rq\,(1-q^2)^2}
{1-q^5-\cfrac{rq^2(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7-\cdots}}}}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r^n}{1-q^{2n+1}}\tag{P}$$
Then the claim for your Q1 follows from setting $r=q$.

Furthermore,
the [already settled](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1461440/75794)
claim for $A(q)$ follows from setting $r=-q$
because there is the known series expansion
$$\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0\mid2\tau)}{2q_4}\right)^2
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n \sum_{d\mid(2n+1)} (-1)^{(d-1)/2}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-q)^n}{1-q^{2n+1}}$$
where the latter Lambert-like series can be understood as a simple sieving
machinery that generates an odd $d$ in every step and updates the counters
associated with all odd multiples of $d$.

I suspect that there are simpler ways of proving proposition (P),
but in the current series of posts regarding such continued fractions
([1st](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457024/75794),
[2nd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1457985/75794),
[3rd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460599/75794),
[4th](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1461440/75794)),
everything starts with the formula from Ramanujan's 2nd notebook, chapter 16,
entry 11:
$$\small\frac{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty - (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty + (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}
= \cfrac{a+b}{1-q+\cfrac{(a+bq)(aq+b)}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q\,(a+bq^2)(aq^2+b)}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^2(a+bq^3)(aq^3+b)}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}\tag{*}$$
The original has the sign of $b$ flipped, but I like to emphasize the symmetry.

To obtain the continued fraction in (P), we would need $ab=-r$ and $a/b=-1$,
which is fulfilled by $\{a,b\}=\{\pm\sqrt{r}\}$.
However, this implies that $a+b=0$, and in that case, Ramanujan's formula
gets reduced to $0=0$. We need to work around that.

We [have already dealt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1461440/75794)
with $a+b=0$, but only for $ab=q$, so we need a new twist here.
First rewrite
$$(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty - (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty
= \overbrace{(-a;q)_\infty\,(a;q)_\infty}^{(a^2;q^2)_\infty}
\left(\frac{(-b;q)_\infty}{(a;q)_\infty}
-\frac{(b;q)_\infty}{(-a;q)_\infty}\right)$$
Then assume $0<|a|<1$ and recall the
[$q$-binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialTheorem.html)
$$\frac{(-b;q)_\infty}{(a;q)_\infty} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{\bigl(-\frac{b}{a};q\bigr)_{n}}{(q;q)_{n}}\,a^{n}$$
which implies
$$\begin{align}
    \frac{(-b;q)_\infty}{(a;q)_\infty}-\frac{(b;q)_\infty}{(-a;q)_\infty}
    &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\bigl(-\frac{b}{a};q\bigr)_{n}}{(q;q)_{n}}
    \,(a^{n}-(-a)^n)
\\  &= 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\bigl(-\frac{b}{a};q\bigr)_{2n+1}}{(q;q)_{2n+1}}
    \,a^{2n+1}
\\  &= 2(a+b)
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\bigl(-\frac{b}{a}q;q\bigr)_{2n}}{(q;q)_{2n+1}}
    \,a^{2n}
\end{align}$$
Voilà, we have a product of $(a+b)$ with a continuous function.
Let's plug that into Ramanujan's formula $(*)$ and cancel the common factor
$(a+b)$:
$$\small\cfrac{1}{1-q+\cfrac{(a+bq)(aq+b)}{1-q^3+\cfrac{q\,(a+bq^2)(aq^2+b)}
{1-q^5+\cfrac{q^2(a+bq^3)(aq^3+b)}{1-q^7+\cdots}}}}
= \frac{2\,(a^2;q^2)_\infty
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-\frac{b}{a}q;q\right)_{2n}}{(q;q)_{2n+1}}\,a^{2n}}
{(-a;q)_\infty\,(-b;q)_\infty + (a;q)_\infty\,(b;q)_\infty}$$
This is continuous across $-\frac{b}{a}=1$, so let us see what happens there.
The denominator of the right-hand side reduces to
$2\,(-a;q)_\infty\,(a;q)_\infty=2\,(a^2;q^2)_\infty$ and therefore gets
cancelled with the $q$-Pochhammer symbol in the numerator. The series simplifies as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(q;q)_{2n}}{(q;q)_{2n+1}}\,a^{2n}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2n}}{1-q^{2n+1}}$$
Thus we obtain
$$\cfrac{1}{1-q-\cfrac{a^2(1-q)^2}{1-q^3-\cfrac{a^2q\,(1-q^2)^2}
{1-q^5-\cfrac{a^2q^2(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7-\cdots}}}}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^{2n}}{1-q^{2n+1}}$$
and now we can replace $a^2$ with $r$ and are almost done.

We had to assume $0<|a|<1$ along the way, which covers all $0<|r|<1$,
but the case $r=0$ needs to be checked separately.
Now $r=0$ causes both sides of (P) to reduce to $1/(1-q)$
because the $r^0$ in the series is to be properly interpreted as $1$
by continuity. Q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

***Too long for a comment***

first let's assume the following identity to be true
$$\frac{1}{q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^{2n-1}} = \cfrac{1}{1-q-\cfrac{q(1-q)^2}{1-q^3-\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)^2}{1-q^5-\cfrac{q^3(1-q^3)^2}{1-q^7-\ddots}}}}$$

Now multiplying both sides by $(1-q)$ and letting $q\rightarrow1$, yields
$$\lim_{q\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n(1-q)}{1-q^{2n-1}}  = \lim_{q\rightarrow1} {\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{\cfrac{q(1-q)}{1-q^2}}{\cfrac{1-q^3}{1-q^2}-\cfrac{\cfrac{q^2(1-q^2)}{1-q^3}}{\cfrac{1-q^5}{1-q^3}-\cfrac{\cfrac {q^3(1-q^3)}{1-q^4}}{\cfrac{1-q^7}{1-q^4}-\ddots}}}}}$$

Which after equivalence transformation becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n-1} = \cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1^2}{3-\cfrac{2^2}{5-\cfrac{3^2}{7-\cfrac{4^2}{9 - \ddots}}}}}$$ 
Which is not a valid identity,since the arctan identity

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}z^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\cfrac{z}{1+\cfrac{(1z)^2}{3+\cfrac{(2z)^2}{5+\cfrac{(3z)^2}{7+\cfrac{(4z)^2}{9 + \ddots}}}}}$$

Is valid for $$|z|\leq1$$ ,$$z\ne i,-i$$

***update*** :In fact this comment does not invalidate the conjectured identity,but rather strengthens it ,since both the series and cfrac approach the same singularity,as observed by Ccorn.Thus the cfrac does not have a finite limit but a singularity.

Comment: Nicco, don't create multiple accounts. It is forbidden.

Comment: @ Tito Piezas :it was a mistake,thing is I'm not yet familiar with this forum,my apologies.

Comment: @Tito piezas:what do you think of the limit?

Comment: I think you may have used an assumption that leads to a conclusion different from mine and ccorn. Anyway, kindly delete this answer **and** new account, and just re-answer (if you still wish) using your correct account.

Comment: Using $z=-\mathrm{i}q$, $q\to1$, both sides diverge, or rather, in $\bar{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ both sides *converge to $\infty$*, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @ccorn :but the arctan identity is violated ,do you agree?

Comment: No, the arctan identity becomes an artanh identity which has poles at $\pm1$. But both sides have such a pole, so there is no demonstrable discrepancy. (I have checked the q-cfrac to high degrees, as Tito has done, and my guess is that the answer to Q1 is yes.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I should have said *singularities*, not *poles*, because besides the removed factor $\frac{1}{1-q}$ there are logarithmic singularities involved: $\operatorname{artanh}q=\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1+q}{1-q}$. This matches the logarithmic divergence of the harmonic-series-like left-hand side as $q\to1$.